# How we see all features of plugins in qgis 2.8.1?

Tags: qgis-2

I have installed Qgis 2.8.1 but in plugins not installed, upgradable are not display. how we add new plugin?

[image: screen shot of plugins windows]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @ADutta! In your plugins interface (shown in the image), go to `Settings > Plugin repositories > Reload all repositories`. See if you can connect.

Answer (score 2):

Select the `ALL` tab[image], And you should see all the others. 
If you go to the settings tab, you can check the `Show experimental plugins` as well.

Make sure you are connected to the repository, and the correct url is defined.
[image]

Comment: Sir, I follow your steps but show that QGIS Official Plugin Repository unavailable.

Comment: @ADutta I've edited my answer, see if that is the way it is defined for you.

Comment: Sir, i have done this process previous and the url is same but status is unavailable.